# How does a .COM file get loaded for execution

Tags: assembly, ms-dos

For a bit of fun I thought I would start writing my own emulator for the 80286. I have been reading a bunch about the topic. I thought for simplicity I would start with a really simple COM executable from the example COM a DOS executable walkthrough [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6L47.png)].

I understand that COM files are loaded directly into memory as is. What I am unclear on is where the stack should be created. Should I create the stack in a new segment? I am guessing I must as the segment with the data and code loaded.

Appreciate any pointers to resources as well.

Comment: The OS creates a new "Process" which is necessary in order to execute something (such as your .COM file). If you launch your .COM file multiple times, each time you do so the OS will create a new "Process". Most of the things you mentioned: memory, stack, "loading", "jumping into", etc., are parts of that Process.

Comment: @rwong Nah, you could just push that COM file straight through the CPU and it would execute. A Process is a construct for protecting applications running on a multithreaded OS from trampling on each other.

Comment: @Craig: In that case, you are treating the COM file as a plain data file, from which you copy the machine instructions into memory, and then execute from your own process.

Comment: @rwong I am trying to emulate simple execution like in MS-DOS where there is no process. The question is about where the stack should be. Should I just create a stack in a new segment of memory. I think the answer is yes, but I would love some validation of this.

Comment: @btlog: Please read the respective Wikipedia articles on [DOS memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS_memory_management), [Conventional memory (DOS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conventional_memory), and [MASM 16-bit memory model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ss9fh0d6.aspx). Unfortunately documentation on MASM (16-bit segmented mode) is fading away on the internet nowadays.

Comment: @btlog: Another thing - even though you said "there is no process", if you try to emulate execution by actually executing them *in the presence of a modern OS*, you have to set the memory page to allow code execution. Otherwise, the CPU is not allowed to feed its execution engine from there. See: [Memory management unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) and [Executable space protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection).

Comment: You can also search through Fabrice or QEMU to get the information you need.

Comment: @rwong thanks for the references. Lots of stuff that I think is going to help.